# three js envMap using one texture

Tags: three.js

I have a code:

```
var urls = [ 'img/effects/cloud.png','img/effects/cloud.png','img/effects/cloud.png','img/effects/cloud.png','img/effects/cloud.png','img/effects/cloud.png' ];
var textureCube = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube( urls, new THREE.CubeRefractionMapping );
var cubeMaterial3 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff, envMap: textureCube,   refractionRatio: 0.98, reflectivity:0.9 } );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( wormholeGeom, cubeMaterial3 );
scene.add(mesh);
```

This successfully works and inserts sphere with refraction map.

But i do not using skybox, but skysphere where is whole sky represented by one texture.
Is the way to make a refraction mapping from one texture?

Not by array of six textures?

I tried many thinks (THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture,THREE.SphericalRefractionMapping too) but no luck.
Documentation is "TODO".

[This](http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/webgl_materials_cubemap_refraction.html) is my goal, but with one texture in skydome. There are used 6 textures in square to make sky.

Comment: You can use http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_shaders_fresnel.html as a template, and modify `THREE.FresnelShader` to use your environment map, instead of a cube map.

Comment: Thank you, I hoped for more simple way. I'm newbie in three.js.

Comment: Can you find a way to convert your environment texture to a cubemap?

Comment: Yes, but i want to automate process of loading textures from database.  This will be unnecessarily complicated solution for me.